# What is the equivalent of a "Good Watch" for an audiobook or record?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, compound-adjectives

We say that a movie is a "good watch" and a book is a "good read".

Somehow, to say that an audiobook or an album is a "good listen" doesn't sound right to my ears, but perhaps that's only because I've never heard it.

Comment: “Good listen” seems normal to me for musical recordings. I haven't noticed it used for audiobooks, but that's mainly because I don't use them.

Comment: I'll go along with "good read" and "good listen" being idiomatic but I've never heard anyone say, "a good watch" and I don't think I'd really like to either.

Comment: I agree with Bradd. A "good listen" is what hundreds of people on Audible.com (the online audiobook purveyor) call the books they like in [their audiobook reviews.](https://www.google.com/#q=%22a+good+listen%22+audible.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are equally correct; depending on which you hear or say most commonly will reflect on which modality you use media the most and will correspond with how correct each one "rings".

"A good listen" is what I use when recommending music: I really can't recall hearing other people use that phrase.  "A good read" is a very common way of recommending a book or article.  I've never heard anyone use "a good watch"/"a good view".  Even so, I'd understand it immediately because of the correspondence with the aforementioned parallels.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Bradd, Jim, JLG. You're right, audio is not my main mode of entertainment, and that's probably why "good listen" sounded odd to me. Good to know that it's in the language, now I can start using it.